# I am getting the error template not found on some other email template although the template is present in sfdc

Tags: visualforce, email-templates, sfdc

I am using a visualforce template using cross objects via apex class as of now. My code was working and sending emails when I was using a custom template with classic letterhead. Send Test and Verify button is still working.

Answer (score 0):

template's id is valid in this org? Template is marked "in development" or "deployed"? Template's body compiles ok? Maybe you removed a field or relationship and it's not valid anymore (although I'd expect the "send test" to fail then too) Template is yours or from managed package? You might not have license?

Can you paste sample of your apex code?